# What does protection mean?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does protection from [quality] do?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/what-does-protection-from-quality-do)

I was playing a match with a friend where I had [Elite Inquisitor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElite%20Inquisitor%5d) on the field against his 3 zombies. Is he able to declare his zombies as blockers even though Elite Inquisitor has "protection" from zombies?  If he can[declare them as blockers] does protection mean that just no damage is dealt by that creature?