# Can a red spell (Sorcery, Instant, etc) affect a green creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a red/green deck. Can I use my red spells on my green creatures, and my green spells on my red creatures?

I am fairly new to MtG so I am sorry if this appears as a sort of nooby question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. If a spell targets a creature, unless it says otherwise, it can target any creature of any colour. The spell's own colour is simply a non-issue.

Consider that if you *did* have to cast red spells on red creatures, or black spells on black creatures, [Doom Blade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoom%20Blade%5d) would be completely useless, being a black spell which says:

> Destroy target nonblack creature.

There are a few exceptions:

- That creature can't have *Hexproof*, unless it's your own creature. Hexproof means your opponents cannot target that creature with their spells or abilities, but you can do so just fine. [Benthic Giant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBenthic%20Giant%5d) is an example of one such creature. If you control a Benthic Giant, you can target it with your own [Auger Spree](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAuger%20Spree%5d) to make it temporarily an 8/1 creature, but your opponent can't cast their own Augur Spree on your Benthic Giant.
- The creature can't have *Shroud*. An example: [Algae Gharial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAlgae%20Gharial%5d). It's an old mechanic which says the creature simply can't be targeted by spells or abilities, *full stop* - not even your own. You won't run into *Shroud* in newer cards, because it's been replaced by *Hexproof*.
- The creature can't have *Protection* from your spell's colour. A creature with protection from a colour cannot be targeted by spells of that colour. (Protection also does [some other good things](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/6915/5573) for you.) For example, [Hand of Honor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHand%20of%20Honor%5d) has *protection from black*, which means it can't be targeted by Doom Blade.

  - Protection can do more than simply pick a colour. [Petrified Wood-Kin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPetrified%20Wood-Kin%5d), for example, can't be targeted by instants, and [Azorius First-Wing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAzorius%20First-Wing%5d) can't be enchanted.
- The creature must otherwise not say it can't be targeted.

And naturally, the creature has to be a valid target for the spell.

The same principles apply to all spells. You can cast [Fade into Antiquity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFade%20into%20Antiquity%5d) on non-green enchantments, and so on.

Comment: To approach this a little more generally, Magic tries to be fairly explicit about things. If you need to care about color, the cards will indicate it somehow. The absolute main thing color matters for is mana costs; the red cards have red mana symbols on them to indicate that you need red mana to cast them. Anything else that cares about color will say so on the card (e.g. "...target red creature...").